# What kind of provisional patent should I get if I want to sell internationally?

Tags: provisional-application, patent-pending, provisional

I have a product i'm looking to get out into the market soon and i'm unsure of what kind of provisional to get. I want to sell the product internationally. Anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one kind of provisional patents.

Each patent application cover only a geographical area (like the USA), so international filling in each jurisdiction is needed if you must have international protection.